# How to .map a column form 1 df for another df by checking the value in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

How to .map 1 column to 2 columns ??

- The goal is to map cost from a REF table to the Data by id.
- The issue .map just compare 1 column with 1 column

The Data is mess up and for some rows there are id names rather then id's.
I could create a new REF table to replace theses id_names to id, the problem is there is so many..

Reff table

```
google =

id   id_name      cost

154  campaign1    15
155  campaign2    12
1566  campaign33  12
158  campaign4    33
```

Data

```
cw = 

id  

154
155
campaign1    
campaign33
1566
158
campaign4
```

Desired output

```
cw =

id            cost

154            15
155            12
campaign1      15
campaign33     12
1566           12
158            33
campaign4      33
```

What I done..

```
# Just work for one column

cw['cost'] = cw['id'].map(google.set_index('id')['cost'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `melt` and map:

```
map_series = google.melt(id_vars='cost').set_index('value')['cost']

cw['cost'] = cw['id'].map(map_series)
```

Comment: can you help with the following question?? 
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739744/how-to-merge-2-df-based-on-comparison-of-2-columns-to-match-1-column  ```