# How to merge 2 df based on comparison of 2 columns to match 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

How to .merge 2 df, 1 column to match 2 columns ??

- The goal is to merge 2 df to have count of records for every campaign id from a REF table to the Data by id.
- The issue .merge just compare 1 column with 1 column

The Data is mess up and for some rows there are id names rather then id's.

It works if I want to merge 1 column to 1 column, or 2 columns to 2 columns, but NOT for 1 column to 2 columns

Reff table

```
g_spend =

campaignid   id_name      cost

154          campaign1    15
155          campaign2    12
1566         campaign33   12
158          campaign4    33
```

Data

```
cw = 

campaignid

154
154
155
campaign1    
campaign33
1566
158
campaign1    
campaign1    
campaign33
campaign4
```

Desired output

```
g_spend =

campaignid  id_name      cost    leads

154        campaign1    15       5
155        campaign2    12       0
1566       campaign33   12       3
158        campaign4    33       2
```

What I done..

```
# Just work for one column

cw.head()
grouped_cw = cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).count()
grouped_cw.rename(columns={'reach':'leads'}, inplace=True)

grouped_cw = pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw)


# now merging
g_spend.campaignid = g_spend.campaignid.astype(str)

g_spend = g_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='campaignid', right_index=True)
```

Comment: @Quang Hoang , Do you have an clue in how I can accomplish that?
I missed this step in my other question, I need the count of leads to be able to get it done

Comment: How did you get those Lead column values in the desired output dataframe, For campaign id 154 there are only 2 values in cw. How did you get 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first set `id_name` as index in `g_spend`, then do a `replace` on `cw`, followed by a `value_counts`:

```
s = (cw.campaignid
       .replace(g_spend.set_index('id_name').campaignid
       .value_counts()
       .to_frame('leads')
    )

g_spend = g_spend.merge(s, left_on='campaignid', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  campaignid     id_name  cost  leads
0        154   campaign1    15      5
1        155   campaign2    12      1
2       1566  campaign33    12      3
3        158   campaign4    33      2
```